# I cannot see the AS statistics in WSO2 BAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-bam

I configure the AS 5.0.0 using this instructions:  -    http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/Setting+up+Service+Statistics+Data+Agent and BAM using this: http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM200/Service+Statistics+Toolbox

When I call a service in AS, Helloworld, I see the data inside cassandra cluster using the explorer but in the Dashboard i cannot see any information only:

No data available. Please visit our docs to see how to configure AS monitoring

Why if I can see the data in cassandra, the Dashboard cannot see it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something happened during the hive analytics run so that summarized data were not properly written to H2 database? Were there any errors during the script execution? If you have changed the summary database to MySQL you will need to change master-datasources.xml in repository location to your MySQL db in order for gadgets to pick up data from that db.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed your stream name in the AS side, please change the "cassandra.cf.name" in the hive script to the same value. Because in the BAM side we persist data in a CF which name equals to your stream name.

Comment: This was the issue I found yesterday Kasun, thanks a lot. In the docummentation in any place say that. Also I found this issue in the logs in AS: TID: [] [Application Server] [2012-10-07 00:42:48,131]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher} -  Session timed out for TCP,192.168.0.145:7611,TCP,192.168.0.145:7711,Thrift Session Expired Exception  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.publisher.client.EventPublisher}